# Laravel many-to-many-to-many relationship with Eloquent?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to have a many-to-many-to-many relationship in Eloquent.
I have 3 tables

- Client
- Assets
- Products

Each client can have many assets.
Each asset can have many products.

At the moment, they are connected with 2 intermediate tables

- client_asset [id|client_id|asset_id]
- asset_products [id|asset_id|product_id]

I think i will now need to connect these 2 intermediate tables together with another intermediate table

- client_asset_asset_products [id|client_asset_id|asset_products_id]

But is this allowed in Eloquent? is it possible? and is it good practise??

How will i connect the 2 intermediate tables with the new intermediate table?

If you imagine it as a client having many buses and each bus can have many passengers... this is what i'm after.

Thanks for any help/info.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine as is. It's up to the ORM to determine which products the client owns and it already has all that information in the DB. With properly named methods for the relationships you could use eager loading like this...

```
$client = Client::with( array( 'assets', 'assets.products' ) )->where_id( 9000 )->first();

// $client->assets array of assets
// $client->assets[0]->products array of products
```

You could also get a flat list of products by doing something like

```
$products = Product::join( 'asset_products', 'asset_product.products.id', '=', 'products.id' )
    ->join( 'client_asset', 'client_asset.assets_id', '=', 'asset_products.assets_id' )
    ->where( 'client_asset.client_id', '=', 9000 )
    ->get( 'products.*' );
```

If this were something I was doing often I would add it as a method to the client model.